# Class dosen't have initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am really new to this and i really need help. I keep getting this problem.
Class `DetailViewController` has no initializers

```
import UIKit

 class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var namelabel : UILabel
@IBOutlet var phoneNumberLabel : UILabel
var contact : Contacts?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let contact = self.contact {
        if let name = contact.name {
            self.namelabel.text = name
        }
        if let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumber {
            self.phoneNumberLabel.text = phoneNumber
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
@IBOutlet var namelabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var phoneNumberLabel : UILabel!
```

You need to either assign a value(in constructor or while defining) to your variables or mark it as optional.